# showing next year date (plus 1 year)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a datepicker field using jquery.datepicker.js

I would like to show the default current date of next year instead of this year. When the user selecting the date it should display current date of next year 2015 instead of 2014.

Below is my draft coding.

```
$(function(){
     $('.default-date-picker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for jQuery DatePicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `minDate` option during initialization:

```
$(function(){
     $('.default-date-picker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        minDate: 365 // days from "today"
    });
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLN8Q/)

If you want to show next year's date initially while still allowing earlier dates to be selectable, use the `defaultDate` option:

```
$('.default-date-picker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    defaultDate: 365 // days from "today"
});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)